# Nginx config for 3rd level domain

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, web-server, https

I know how to create an nginx config for a website with htts so that it redirects to the https domain:

```
  server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server;
      server_name my_domain.com www.my_domain.com;
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name localhost www.my_domain.com;
    return 301 https://my_domain.com$request_uri;
  }

  server {
      listen 443 ssl default_server;
      listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
      server_name my_domain.com;
      # ................
```

Now I'm setting up the domain "staging" in addition to the main one "my_domain.com" I already have. That is, "staging.my_domain.com"
How should I change the config above for "staging.my_domain.com"? I can't figure out. Should I remove the 1st section completely since there can't be www.staging.my_domain.com

If not, then how should my config look like exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the subdomain. There's no reason you can't have www.a.b.c.d.e.f.g.example.com. Typically www isn't added in front of subdomain names though.

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
  server_name staging.example.com;
  # locations etc
}
```

Add a port 80 server to forward if you like.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name staging.example.com;
  return 301 https://staging.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Note that "example.com" is used for examples as per standards.

Comment: all will remain the same except that I add "staging." in front of each one, right?

Comment: Yes. Define and domain name you want, second, third, fourth level.